# How do i add upp the values in list of list of lists together?

Tags: python, list, tuples, addition

I have this single list of list of lists, (that I got from doing 3 choose 2 combination on a list of lists):

[([1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 10]), ([1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 100]), ([1, 0, 1, 10], [1, 1, 0, 100])]

so its 3 groups, these 3 groups have 2 lists each, and these 2 lists have 4 integers each

I want to add the integers up in these pairs of lists to make one list of sums for each group.
It should look like:

([2,0,2,11],     [2,1,1,101],     [2,1,1,110])

To show the problem here easily, I simplified the example to "3 groups of 2 lists with 4 integers " but in reality its about "1000 groups of 10 lists of 30 integers".

I tried googling how to do this and got some lambda and zip stuff but I couldn't get it to work. I tried making a custom loop as well, I mostly got recommended cases of adding list1 to list2 , but i just have one list. I got bunch of errors. I appreciate if anyone could help, thank you.

Comment: please also share your `zip` attempts, even if they don't work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's a solution using `sum` and `zip`:

```py
result = [[sum(row) for row in zip(*pair)] for pair in data]
```

You can break each call down and add prints to better understand what each part does, I'll try and explain:

Comment: God bless your soul, worked perfectly <3

Answer (score 0):

What other posts are missing out, is that this problem must be generalizable to OPs request. It must work on `"1000 groups of 10 lists of 30 integers"`. Therefore the following solution:

```py
tuple([sum(q[i] for q in p) for i in range(len(p[0]))] for p in l)
```

This list generator sums up the columns of each list, where each list is a part of the main list, just like described in OP. This problem is generalizable since it now is not delimited to a sum of 2 lists, but a sum of all lists.

Comment: Edit: referred `other posts` have been deleted

Answer (score 0):

You could use numpy in order to add the arrays, but you will get a numpy array as a resksksult.

```
import numpy as np
lista = [([1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 10]), ([1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 100]), ([1, 0, 
        1, 10], [1, 1, 0, 100])]
list(map(lambda x: np.array(x[0]) + np.array(x[1]), lista))
```